# How to Reorder dynamic inputs in react?

Tags: reactjs, input, dynamic

I am new to React and so far I've only learned to code with hooks.

I made dynamic inputs where the user can add as many inputs as they want.
I'd like to allow the user to rearrange the order of the inputs.

I tried some code (see below) But it ended up in warning.

> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled.

How could I rearrange the order of the inputs?

[image]

```js
const Questions = ({ questionsData, setQuestionsData, title, id }) => {
  console.log(questionsData);
  const handleSave = async () => {
    if (id) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/update", {
          id: id,
          title: title,
          questions: questionsData,
        });
        alert(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    } else if (!id && title !== "") {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/create", {
          title: title,
          questions: questionsData,
        });
        alert(response.data.message);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    } else {
      alert("Le Formulaire doit avoir un titre.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {questionsData.map((question, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={question + index} className="questions">
            <div className={question.type === "texte" ? "orange" : "red"}>
              <span>{question.type === "texte" ? "1" : "2"}</span>
              <img src={Minus} alt="" />
              <img
                src={question.type === "texte" ? FileWhite : StarWhite}
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Ecrivez votre question"
              value={question.title}
              onChange={(event) => {
                let tab = [...questionsData];
                tab[index].title = event.target.value;
                tab[index].index = index;
                setQuestionsData(tab);
              }}
            ></input>
            <div>
              <img
                src={ChevronUp}
                alt="move up"
                onClick={() => {
                  let tab = [...questionsData];
                  let item = tab.splice(index, 1);
                  tab.splice(index + 1, 0, item);
                  setQuestionsData(tab);
                }}
              />
              <img src={ChevronDown} alt="move down" />
              <img
                src={SmallTrash}
                alt="delete question"
                onClick={() => {
                  let tab = [...questionsData];
                  tab.splice(index, 1);
                  setQuestionsData(tab);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div className="questionType">
        <div
          className="addText"
          onClick={() => {
            let tab = [...questionsData];
            tab.push({ type: "texte", title: "", index: "" });
            setQuestionsData(tab);
          }}
        >
          <img src={File} alt="" />
          <p>Ajouter une question "Texte"</p>
        </div>
        <div
          className="addNote"
          onClick={() => {
            let tab = [...questionsData];
            tab.push({ type: "note", title: "", index: "" });
            setQuestionsData(tab);
          }}
        >
          <img src={Star} alt="" />
          <p>Ajouter une question "Note"</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="save">
        <button onClick={handleSave}>Sauvegarder</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Questions;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your move up logic adds to index which should be `index-1`, also make sure to check for array bounds if `index+1` is less than or equal to `questions.length` and `index-1` is greater than `0`. I fixed the move up issue in a sandbox. Check below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-chatelet-ryo41?file=/src/Questions.js

Comment: Yeah sorry I changed the move up after pasting the code here.
I just forgot in my onclick move up and down to add [0] to item.
I wrote  tab.splice(index + 1, 0, item);
instead of tab.splice(index + 1, 0, item[0]);
Now it works perfectly.
Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: @FlorieAnstett do mark as approved answer if it is correct.